# When do I need to use the &quot; in xml?

Tags: xml

When I have quotes that are not in an attribute do I need to encode them using `&quot;`?

Which is correct?  Exhibit A or Exhibit B?

### Exhibit A

```
<boat>
    <name> Bertha </name>
    <description> Good boat.  10 feet long.  "Fixer-upper"</description>
</boat>
```

### Exhibit B

```
<boat>
    <name> Bertha </name>
    <description> Good boat.  10 feet long.  &quot;Fixer-upper&quot;</description>
</boat>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both of your examples are valid.

You only need `&quot;` inside an attribute value; a `"` character would close the attribute early.

Comment: More specifically — an attribute value delimited with double quotes. `foo='bar " baz'` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx):

`&quot;` must be used for an attribute value, but a straight quotation mark (") is acceptable as the content of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and valid XML.

There is no need to use `&quote;` within text nodes.

Comment: This should be `&quot;`, not `&quote;`.

Answer (score -1):

like this is ok
`<boat                                                                                         description = " Good boat.  10 feet long.  &quot;Fixer-upper&quot;"></boat>`

like this is not ok
`<boat                                                                                         description = " Good boat.  10 feet long.  "Fixer-upper""></boat>`