# How can I save this token as a string value in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>";
```

I can't save this token as a string value, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the `"` with `\`:

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case the quotation characters need to be escaped by prefixing with `\`:

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

But note that in XML, you need to use `&quot;` to escape the quotation character in an attribute value:

[When do I need to use the &quot; in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186179/when-do-i-need-to-use-the-quot-in-xml)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape double quotes by backslashes:

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, \", on the interior quotes. In your example, to save this Token as a String value

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>";
```

you would write

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1="<?xml version='1.0"encoding='UTF-8"?>"
```

use

```
String str1 = "<?xml version=\'1.0\"encoding=\'UTF-8\"?>";
```

For your case use

```
String str2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can write like this:

```
String xmlHeader = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
```