# How to encode special characters in XML

Tags: c#, xml

My string XML contains a whole series of special characters:

```
&amp;
egrave;
&amp;
rsquo;
&amp;
rsquo;
&amp;
rsquo;
&amp;
ldquo;
&amp;
rdquo;
&amp;
rsquo
&amp;
agrave;
&amp;
agrave;
```

I need replace this special characters in insert string in DB and I tried use **System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode** without success, can you help me?

```
string sql = "insert into rss (title, description, link, pubdate) values (?,?,?, " +
             " STR_TO_DATE(?, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s GMT'));";

OdbcCommand command;
OdbcDataAdapter adpter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
connection.Open();
command = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlTitle.InnerText.ToString()));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlDescription.InnerText.ToString()));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlLink.InnerText.ToString()));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param4", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlPubDate.InnerText.ToString()));
adpter.InsertCommand = command;
adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Do you need them to be encoded when stored in DB? Can't you simply store raw text (without encoding) and then encode them back if/when you write them in an HTML page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode or with .NET 4.0+ you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Comment: You probably mean `HtmlEncode`

Answer (score 23):

You can use a native .NET method for escaping special characters in text. Sure, there's only like 5 special characters, and 5 Replace() calls would probably do the trick, but I'm sure there's got to be something built-in.

Example of converting `"&"` to `"&amp;"`

To much relief, I've discovered a native method, hidden away in the bowels of the SecurityElement class. Yes, that's right - SecurityElement.Escape(string s) will escape your string and make it XML safe.

This is important, since if we are copying or writing data to Infopath Text fields, it needs to be first Escaped to non-Entity character like `"&amp;"`.

invalid XML Character  to Replaced With

`"<" to "&lt;"`

`">" to "&gt;"`

`"\"" to "&quot;"`

`"'" to "&apos;"`

`"&"  to "&amp;"`

Namespace is "System.Security". Refer : http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(VS.80).aspx

The Other Option is to Customise code for

```
public static string EscapeXml( this string s )
{
  string toxml = s;
  if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( toxml ) )
  {
    // replace literal values with entities
    toxml = toxml.Replace( "&", "&amp;" );
    toxml = toxml.Replace( "'", "&apos;" );
    toxml = toxml.Replace( "\"", "&quot;" );
    toxml = toxml.Replace( ">", "&gt;" );
    toxml = toxml.Replace( "<", "&lt;" );
  }
  return toxml;
}

public static string UnescapeXml( this string s )
{
  string unxml = s;
  if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( unxml ) )
  {
    // replace entities with literal values
    unxml = unxml.Replace( "&apos;", "'" );
    unxml = unxml.Replace( "&quot;", "\"" );
    unxml = unxml.Replace( "&gt;", ">" );
    unxml = unxml.Replace( "&lt;", "<" );
    unxml = unxml.Replace( "&amp;", "&" );
  }
  return unxml;
}
```

Comment: If using @DmytroKhmara's custom code, `toxml = toxml.Replace( "&", "&amp;" );` needs to be the first replace in `EscapeXML`. Otherwise, you'll escape the ampersands in all of the other escaped characters.

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder to do the Replace calls.  It will do them in-place and not spin off 5 garbage strings.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` you have to use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode`

Comment: What is my XML contains something like <LEDGER NAME="&quot;Radheshyam Trivedi & Others, Devanshi Corporation&quot;" RESERVEDNAME="">

Comment: Using html.decode will change it to <LEDGER NAME=""Radheshyam Trivedi & Others, Devanshi Corporation"" RESERVEDNAME=""> where when parsing it using XElement or XDocument will throw an error because of double quotes for the attribute NAME

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 other ways this can be done from what you tried:

1. Use string.Replace() 5 times
2. Use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()
3. System.Xml.XmlTextWriter

I could explain each case but I found [this link to be mightily useful](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/2008/10/21/different-ways-how-to-escape-an-xml-string-in-c/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` to encode special characters in XML.

Like this:

```
var val = "test&<";
var node = new XElement("Node");
node.Value = val ?? node.Value;
Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
```

OUTPUT:

> "<Node>test&amp;&lt;</Node>"

Answer (score 3):

The ready to use XML escape function for .NET 5+:

```
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(s))]
static string? XmlEscape(string? s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return s;

    var node = new XElement("X") { Value = s };
    return node.ToString()[3..^4];
}
```

Usage example:

```
Console.WriteLine(XmlEscape("Hello < & >"));
```

The produced output:

```
Hello &lt; &amp; &gt;
```

Comment: Does not work for double quotes e.g. XmlEscape("\"");

Comment: @DejanDular, `"` character is allowed in XML, so it should not be escaped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186179/when-do-i-need-to-use-the-quot-in-xml

Comment: @ogggre `"` must be encoded within XML attribute values that are delimited by that character, just like `'`

Answer (score 1):

`Statement toxml = toxml.Replace( "&", "&amp;" );`

This has to be done first.  Otherwise, when calling this last will replace all the previous "&" (' or  ") with &s;

Answer (score 0):

Simple code:

```
    public static string ToXmlStr(string value) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "" : value.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("<", "&lt;");

    public static string FromXmlStr(string xmlStr) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlStr) ? "" : xmlStr.Replace("&apos;", "'").Replace("&quot;", "\"").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&amp;", "&");

    public static string ToMultilineXmlStr(string value) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "" :
        value.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n').Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s, n) => s.Append("<p>").Append(ToXmlStr(n)).Append("</p>\n")).ToString();
```

Please note: for multiline values in xml usualy yon need to incapsulate each line into `<p> tag. So "<'&A'>\n<'&B'>" => "<p>&lt;&amp;A;&gt;</p><p>&lt;&amp;B;&gt;</p>"`